# JOINS in NoSQL databases

Tags: mongodb, solr, nosql

I've hit a problem devleoping document structure for Apache Solr (however, I guess this problem is simple and common to other NoSQL engines). I've a document that should contain zillion of user references (e.g. zillion of fields in it). In RDBMS I'd use 2 simple tables with one-to-many relations. However how is that achieved in NoSQL (especially Solr)? Won't the document with zillion of fields (multivalued) become too heavy-weight? Solr does not support document update on field-level. It should be updated as a whole and this is too costly ;(

Comment: Why a zillion fields instead of a single multivalued field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Solr, but MongoDB indeed doesn't have joins. You can embed related data inside its parent entity (it is quite natural for `User` object to embed user roles).

If, however, because of this embedding document might outgrow its limit (currently 16M per document), then you have no choice but to store this related data in separate documents (either as individual documents or grouped into several document-batches).

If you store data separately from its main entity, then, naturally, you have to perform more than one query to fetch all the data. Not sure how Solr will like this.

MongoDB supports in-place partial updating of documents.

Comment: how is the performance of searching for field matching some criteri inside 16M document, containing most of fields - the `user` field with different user names?

Comment: If, for example, document has structure `{users: [name1, name2, ...]}` and `users` field is indexed, then it's cheap to locate documents that contain given names.

Comment: This is for MongoDB, confirm.

Comment: This is for MongoDB, confirmed :-)

Comment: Thank you :) If that's cheap - this is a right way to use it. What would you suggest - is that better to keep user names as strings, or user ids as integer? I'm absolutelly new to MongoDB. Does it makes any difference and type optimization?

Comment: Depends. I would assume that average user name is longer than 4 bytes, thus it is more efficient to store user ids (in int32, for example).
Also integers can be processed more efficiently than strings.

Comment: nonrel django achieves this under the hood for you. maybe some references for ya:  http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about solr, but playOrm helps do joins BUT it is on partitions of a table(not the whole table).  So if you partition by month or account, you just grab that partition and query into it with normal SQL.  Not sure that will help you at all or not.